# Sort multi dimensional array based on sum of internal arrays in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Let's say I have a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
(
    (2, 2, 1),
    (0, 1, 2),
    (0, 1, 1),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 2),
    (0, 1, 3),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (1, 3, 3)
)
```

Now I need to sort this array in descending order of the internal array's sum.

I tried by adding this array and another array of the sum values in a dictionary, but it doesn't work if the sum contains similar numbers.

i.e, I want the result to be:

```
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 2, 1),
(0, 1, 3),
(0, 1, 2),
(0, 1, 1),
(0, 0, 2),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with key-value coding:

```
NSArray *array = …; // Whatever you have

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"@sum.self" ascending:NO]; // @sum is an aggregate
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Fonix's answer is cool, but it's Swift, In Obj-C then do like this:

```
NSArray *numArray = @[@[@1,@1,@1], @[@0,@0,@0], @[@2,@2,@2], @[@0,@1,@2]];

NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [numArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSNumber *first = [(NSArray *)a valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
        NSNumber *second = [(NSArray *)b valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];

NSLog(@"sorted %@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: oops completely missed the objective-c part, doh

Comment: :D other ppl can search for it in the future so it's still worth keep

Comment: thanks for the effort, but the KVC answer by @Amin Negm-Awas is comparatively easier.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work

```
let multiDimenArray = [[0,1,2],[2,3,4],[1,2,3]]

let sorted = multiDimenArray.sort { a, b -> Bool in

    let aR = a.reduce(0, combine:+) //sums the numbers inside a
    let bR = b.reduce(0, combine:+)

    return aR > bR //swap direction of > if you want ascending or descending
}

print(sorted);
```

prints

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
```

edit:

doh, brain forgot that it should be in objective-c

Comment: Worth noting you can just pass the `+` operator into the `combine:` argument of `reduce`, as Swift treats it as a function.